# How to drop an element into a div only when the element and div have the same id in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to drag and drop an element to a div(where multiple div exist) but the element should be drop-able only if the element's id and the div's id is matching(like get the id of the div which the image is being dragged upon and give it a value and compare with the dragged image id and if matched then dropped). I am new to java script, so any help is appreciated!

Here is the code:  [jsfiddle.net/8m6982qf](http://%20jsfiddle.net/8m6982qf)

Comment: can you please post your code you've trued ?

Comment: First thing that jumps out, IDs **should** be unique, otherwise they won't work as you're probably expecting.

Comment: create a fiddle for clear understanding.

Comment: @UsmanRana here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/8m6982qf/ but for now i can drop the image anywhere.

Comment: @RanjitSingh This is the code jsfiddle.net/8m6982qf but for now i can drop the image anywhere.

Comment: @Hodrobond yes, now I think of it, it would't work but what I need to do is get the id of the div which the image is being dragged upon and give it a value and compare with the dragged element id.

Comment: Edit your question with the code, comments are not ment for that. Use the code snippet-tool for that.

Comment: @Esko Sorry, I am new here and Thank you!

Comment: with element id you mean image id?

Comment: @Shubh yes with the image id.

Comment: @KaiMutum posted my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can keep the allowed data in your div and then can compare if the id of image matches with div allowed data then only append else do nothing

Html

```
<p>Drag an image into the right Box:</p>
<div>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-allowed="boy"></div>
    <div id= "div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-allowed="man"></div>
    <br>
</div>
<div  class="title"><p><span id="left">Boy</span><span id="right">Man</span></p></div>
<br>
<div class="images">
    <img id="boy" src="http://images.fitpregnancy.mdpcdn.com/sites/fitpregnancy.com/files/styles/width_360/public/toddler-wearing-headphones_600x600_shutterstock_93821278.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100" onclick="reply_click(this.id)">
    <img id="man" src="http://creativestockphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/images-of-man-and-woman-in-love.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100" onclick="reply_click(this.id)">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); 
}
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
    return clicked_id;
}
function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      if(ev.target.getAttribute("data-allowed")==data)
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

You can check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8m6982qf/5/)

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for!